# iPhone autoresizing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, autoresize

Is there a "stick-to-bottom" autoresizing mode in Cocoa-Touch? Basically, I got a UIImageView in the lower part of another UIView. When the UIView resizes, I don't want to change the UIImageView's size, but keep it in the lower part of the UIView, while only resizing the other subviews in my UIView above the UIImageView.

Is that easily feasible?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to have the image view resize horizontally:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```