# How do I glue ADBannerView to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I'm trying to add an iAd to the bottom of a Cordova iPad application. I can get the banner to display, but can't figure out how to get it to stay at the bottom.

Currently this displays the banner right below the status bar:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, adView.frame.size.height, adView.frame.size.width);
    [adView setHidden:NO];
    NSLog(@"show the banner");
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [adView setHidden:YES];
    NSLog(@"hide the banner");
}
```

In viewDidLoad I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    adView.delegate = self;
    [adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [adView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set auto resizing mask of your `adView`. Try to select all EXCEPT, top and flexible height.

**Edit:**

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869280/uiview-to-stick-at-bottom-of-uiscrollview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046414/iphone-autoresizing) threads.

Comment: When I do this the banner is stuck in the vertical center of the screen for some reason. [adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];

Comment: Is your view rotated ? Why are setting `adView` frame in `bannerViewDidLoadAd` ?

Comment: The app goes into landscape mode when the iPad is rotated. I'm just trying things to get it to work. The auto resizing doesn't seem to do anything. Is there something else I need to do to enable auto resizing?

Comment: For landscape height becomes width, try using flexible height instead of flexible width.